# JQuery AJAX div.load form elements not submitting on mobile (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I've got a drop down box which populates a div onchange with the following AJAX call:

```
$('#styleget').html(ajax_load).load('/Order/NewStyling?prd=' + $('#Product').val());
```

The div is displayed correctly and contains a number of form elements.

When I submit this form on my desktop, the form elements are returned to the controller as part of my object.
When I submit this form on my iPhone, Nook or Droid Tab, I get an error because the collection of objects from the div doesn't seem to be submitting.

I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance about using such a method on a mobile platform (which I don't have much experience with).

Thanks

**Resolution**
The parent page was populating the styleget div with a form from another page. The problem was that two  tags were being generated (one by the parent, one by the child form) which was confusing mobile.
I removed @Using Html.BeginForm from the view and it works!

Comment: Could you show us a little more code from your view and scripts. It is not quite clear what is going on currently. What is `styleget`, what is `ajax_load`, what is `#Product`, how does the HTML form look like, ...?

Comment: Thanks for the help Darin.
I struggled to articulate the question properly on here because I wasn't sure if it was a JQuery problem, Mobile problem or ASP.NET MVC problem.
It turns out to be an ASP.NET MVC problem, or at least my ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

The parent page was populating the styleget div with a form from another page. The problem was that two tags were being generated (one by the parent, one by the child form) which was confusing mobile. I removed @Using Html.BeginForm from the view and it works!